# How can I create ECDSA key pairs without any third party API in android

Tags: android, cryptography, ecdsa

I need to create ECDSA key pairs. But I don't want to use any third party API like "bouncy castle" or "spongy castle". I have found this doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.html But this will only work on android 6.0. But I want to support lower versions too.

Comment: *But I don't want to use any third party API like "bouncy castle"* - BouncyCastle is included in Android.

Comment: but i will need to add library for that, right ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I don't know which version of BouncyCastle version supports it and which BouncyCastle version is included in which Android version. Anyway, what's with the aversion of including an additional library for your app? If it's the size, you can rip out the necessary code from the library, because it's under MIT license.

Comment: No, you wont be able to use ECDSA in KeyPairGenerator class, below API 23 as it doesn't supports. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#SupportedKeyPairGenerators